# How to inflate View on my layout?

Tags: android, android-view, android-linearlayout

How to inflate View on layout, where all my ui elements which are on layout should be visible.
Am trying this lines but it is not working am not able to see  my background image, button and other images.

> MyView view1=new MyView(this);

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 view1= (MyView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
```

Please help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is this cast for "(MyView)"..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you are doing, use

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

The reason for not getting your view after inflating is that you need to add that View in the current View somewhere. Currently your inflated view is orphaned.

Comment: ur rite, bt i have added my view in current view stil am not getting. Actually, i have one class extends View where i draw a lines on my view. in activity layout xml i have added background imageViews and butons.which are not visible. But am  able to draw lines perfectly. I thk u got my prob..

Answer (score 1):

this usually works...

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View view1= inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
```

or

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext);
View view1= inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
```

and then add this view to the contentView.

**Updated:**

Assuming you have need to draw a line in your main.xml, let me give you this suggestion. instead of drawing line at runtime by extending View class, create a View in xml like this

```
<View android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
      android:layout_height = "2dp"  //assuming you want line of 2dp thickness
      android:background= "@android:color/black"/> // define your desired color here
```

hope it helps..

Comment: @ntc.. Myview is my view class.

Comment: Myview extends View class . where i can draw the line. And i have set view to contentview but it is not working

Comment: @Hema.. why do you even want to do that.. create a line in xml and then set it as content view... not much complex stuff as you are doing..

Answer (score 0):

This worked  finally.

```
getWindow().addContentView(view1,
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                         ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```